# Sequential-access I/O to unit open for direct access conflict with NetCDF

Tags: io, fortran, netcdf, sequential

I have a Fortran program that I've been running on Linux without major issues. Today I compiled it for OS X and I got the following error:
`sequential-access I/O to unit open for direct access`

I simplified the program to a minimal working example to reproduce the error:

```
program read_nc
    integer :: jday, year
    NAMELIST/date/jday, year
    open(10,file='realtime.crd',form='formatted',status='old')
    read(unit=10,nml=date)
    close(10)
end program
```

I compiled it with ifort:
`ifort test_open_osx.f90`
, ran the program and I had no issues, i.e. I could not reproduce the error found in the complete program.

After some time examining the potential sources of error, I decided to link the netCDF library in the 'simple test program' above, given that my complete program uses the netCDF library. So now, without changing the source code I tried compiling as `ifort test_open_osx.f90 -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdff` which compiled without errors. I then ran it and to my surprise, the error appeared:

```
forrtl: severe (259): sequential-access I/O to unit open for direct access, unit 10, file realtime.crd
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
libnetcdff.6.dyli  0000000105CB4C11  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000105BC4188  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000105BBA9CD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000105BBA88E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Why is the netCDF library conflicting with this simple statement? can I fix it with a simple compiler option? I don't want to compromise the source code since it works on my Linux workstation just fine, I just wanted to continue working with it on my laptop.

PS: the structure of the file that I am attempting to read is:

```
&sunrise_parms
JDATE   = 20130101 
/

&date
jday    = 001
year    = 2013
/
```

PS: On linux I am also using ifort

Comment: Which compiler was used to compile NetCDFm It **must** be the same compiler you are using for your program. Otherwise the runtime IO libraries of different compilers may cause the strangest things.

Comment: Ok, are you sure you are compiling the EXACT code that is in the question above? Be sure there is no difference, not even a small one. No call to NetCDF there.

Comment: Try changing the unit to a higher number, for example 200 instead of 10. You have to change that in `open`, `read` and `close`

Comment: Better yet, use the `newunit` specifier instead.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, netCDF was also compiled with ifort, and yes the exact code was used (I didn't even add an "Include" for netCDF). The only difference was at the compilation stage, in which I linked to netCDF. I also tried with different unit numbers, and also with the newunit specifier on open, read and close. None of these suggestions fixed the problem.

Comment: The proboem might be in the compiler and its installation. I would contact Intel Support Forum.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be linking in the `netcdf` library as well as `netcdff`?

Comment: I initially had -lnetcdff -lnetcdf, the same error occurred. While we are on the subject..why do I need to link -lnetcdf? isn't the extra f for fortran, while the one without the extra f is for c?

Comment: Anyway, I'll try and re-compile netCDF again when I have time, I'll let you know if that fixes the problem. Now that I think about it, the last time I compiled it was when I had 'Mavericks', and now I have 'El Capitan'

Comment: Simply put, libnetcdff.x is a wrapper of functions in libnetcdf.x. libnetcdf fortran is not a standalone, it is strongly dependent on the c version.